# Use ngFor with async pipe to display array of observables

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having a hard time understanding why ngFor isn't working with an array of observables.

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    dwsubscriptions: Observable<Dwsubscription>[] = new Array();

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dwsubscriptions.push(
            this.devicewiseService.getSubscription('Randomizer', '1', 3, 1, -1)
        )
    }
}
```

Then my html

```
<div *ngFor="let dwsubscription of dwsubscriptions | async">
    <p>value: {{dwsubscription.params.data}}</p>
</div>
```

getSubscriptions is returning an observable

```
getSubscription(device: string, variable: string, type: number, count:number, length:number): Observable<Dwsubscription> {
```

I am getting the error

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe
>   'AsyncPipe'

This works fine if I do async pipe on a single observable returned from getSubscription(). Why can't I push those observables to an array and then iterate through them in my template using ngFor?

Comment: `dwsubscriptions` is not an Observable / async. It seems like you want to do `*ngFor="let dwsubscription of dwsubscriptions"` and then `{{ (dwsubscription | async).params.data`

Comment: A better question is why do you have an array of Observables vs. getting an array of data from one Observable?

Comment: I would suggest you to use forkJoin from the component itself

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of observables. You'll have to loop over each observable and then use the async pipe for each one.

Try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let dwsubscription of dwsubscriptions">
  <div *ngIf="dwsubscription | async as dw">
    <p>value: {{dw.params.data}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies that you want an array of Observables. That means you would need to fix how you reference `dwsubscriptions` in your html. dwsubscriptions **is not** an Observable in your example. It is an array of Observables. So no need to use the `async` pipe on `dwsubscriptions` ;

[Heres a quick Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arryn1)

The chaing comes from:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let obs of dwsubscriptions">
  {{obs | async | json}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using joinFork

```
this.results = forkJoin(this.locations, this.distances).pipe(
  map(([locations, distances]) => locations.concat(distances))
```

);